# Is is possible to connect MySQL with Power BI Report Server?

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I want to show my data in power BI report server directly from mysql database.

Comment: it is possible , you can built a getaway for example

Comment: Seems so an lots of stuff pops up if you google mysql power bi

Comment: yes, you can do this. you can setup the gateway in PowerBi

Answer (score 0):

This is the perfect match for you. Here is the [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggpn3-4FB4s)

Here is the official [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-source-prerequisites) from MS

Here is the community [question](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Trying-to-connect-to-MY-SQL-from-Power-BI/td-p/195060) regarding PowerBI and MySQL